# HP dual boot kali wifi not working

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

I'm new to Kali and I saw in StackExchange some guy told to follow the below steps to fix it. I tried but I got the error below. I think there is a problem with firmware in my case please help

**Solution offered:**

Nearly all of hp laptops have this issue , it's the wifi adapter which only has one antenna and so you need to install a different firmware. I have to do it again and again so I made a script. Plug an Ethernet connection using USB tethering and

make a file `fixwifi.sh` using

```
nano fixwifi.sh
```

Copy the contents

```
apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r) git build-essential dkms
git clone git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sudo modprobe rtl8723de
echo "options rtl8723de ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf
```

Save the file with

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

Execute it using

```
chmod +x fixwifi.sh && ./fixwifi.sh
```

and you are good to go.

```
Error:Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.8).
dkms is already the newest version (2.8.2-2).
git is already the newest version (1:2.27.0-1).
linux-headers-5.6.0-kali2-amd64 is already the newest version (5.6.14-2kali1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 884 not upgraded.
fatal: Too many arguments.
```

usage: `git clone [<options>] [--] <repo> [<dir>]`

```
-v, --verbose         be more verbose
-q, --quiet           be more quiet
--progress            force progress reporting
-n, --no-checkout     don't create a checkout
--bare                create a bare repository
--mirror              create a mirror repository (implies bare)
-l, --local           to clone from a local repository
--no-hardlinks        don't use local hardlinks, always copy
-s, --shared          setup as shared repository
--recurse-submodules[=<pathspec>]
                      initialize submodules in the clone
--recursive ...       alias of --recurse-submodules
-j, --jobs <n>        number of submodules cloned in parallel
--template <template-directory>
                      directory from which templates will be used
--reference <repo>    reference repository
--reference-if-able <repo>
                      reference repository
--dissociate          use --reference only while cloning
-o, --origin <name>   use <name> instead of 'origin' to track upstream
-b, --branch <branch>
                      checkout <branch> instead of the remote's HEAD
-u, --upload-pack <path>
                      path to git-upload-pack on the remote
--depth <depth>       create a shallow clone of that depth
--shallow-since <time>
                      create a shallow clone since a specific time
--shallow-exclude <revision>
                      deepen history of shallow clone, excluding rev
--single-branch       clone only one branch, HEAD or --branch
--no-tags             don't clone any tags, and make later fetches not to follow them
--shallow-submodules  any cloned submodules will be shallow
--separate-git-dir <gitdir>
                      separate git dir from working tree
-c, --config <key=value>
                      set config inside the new repository
--server-option <server-specific>
                      option to transmit
-4, --ipv4            use IPv4 addresses only
-6, --ipv6            use IPv6 addresses only
--filter <args>       object filtering
--remote-submodules   any cloned submodules will use their remote-tracking branch
--sparse              initialize sparse-checkout file to include only files at root
```

**Error!**

```
Could not find module source directory.
Directory: /usr/src/.-rtlwifi_new does not exist.
Error! Could not find module source directory.
Directory: /usr/src/rtlwifi-new-0.6 does not exist.
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8723de not found.
options rtl8723de ant_sel=2
```

My `$ lspci -vq` results

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
        DeviceName: Hanksville Gbe Lan Connection
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
        Memory at b1104000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Memory at b1100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
        Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=4 Masked-
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
        Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Capabilities: [178] L1 PM Substates
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter
        DeviceName: Hanksville Gbe Lan Connection
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
        I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
        Memory at b1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [148] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [168] Device Serial Number 00-e0-4c-00-00-00-00-00
        Capabilities: [178] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Capabilities: [180] L1 PM Substates
        Kernel modules: wl


iwconfig results:
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

usb0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          
wlan1     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          
hwsim0    no wireless extensions.


ifconfig results:

eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 18:60:24:14:83:0b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 12  bytes 556 (556.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 12  bytes 556 (556.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.42.53  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.42.255
        inet6 2401:4900:2586:2d5e:d805:78ff:fe65:65b3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::d805:78ff:fe65:65b3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2401:4900:2586:2d5e:fd3a:dc44:a795:21ca  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether da:05:78:65:65:b3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 32851  bytes 37101808 (35.3 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 21202  bytes 3335363 (3.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 52:fd:b2:36:a8:38  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 72:06:d6:de:52:48  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The first actual error message is:

```
fatal: Too many arguments.

usage: git clone [<options>] [--] <repo> [<dir>]
[... rest of git usage message omitted ...]
```

This should tell you that there is something that should not be there in a `git clone` command in the script. The relevant line is:

```
git clone git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
```

The `git clone` should not be repeated like that.

The subsequent error messages are caused by the first failure: because `git` could not download the source code of the `rtl8723de` module, the commands intended to compile that source code and install the resulting driver will of course also fail.

Your `lspci -vq` output also indicates that your RTL8723DE card is currently used by the `wl` driver, and the script does nothing to change that.

If you actually [read the GitHub page of the driver the script will download](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new), you will see this text:

> The master branch of this repo is officially abandoned. If you are running a kernel newer than 5.0, use the drivers built into your kernel. That is a lot less work.

If you look at the sub-page of the `extended` branch which the script attempts to use, you'll also find this:

> The extended branch of this repo is officially abandoned. If you are running a kernel newer than 5.0, use the drivers built into your kernel. That is a lot less work.

Both branches also include this advice:

> If you are using a Realtek RTL8723DE, RTL8822BE, RTL8822CE, or RTL8821CE, then you need the rtw88 branch:

This suggests the advice & script you are trying to use **may be already obsolete**, as both the driver development and the kernel version in Kali have marched on since the advice & script were written.

But if you still want to try this driver, I would suggest a modified version of the script:

```
apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r) git build-essential dkms
git clone -b rtw88 https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
echo "options rtl8723de ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf
echo "blacklist wl" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de wl && sudo modprobe rtl8723de
```

So, the modifications on the `git clone` line will remove the doubled command, and change the branch of the driver from the abandoned `extended` to the currently-recommended `rtw88`. I added blacklisting for your current `wl` driver, so that the new `rt8723de` module will be able to take its place. I also changed the order of operations a little, so that if the module will actually get loaded without a reboot, it will also pick up the `ant_sel=2` option. But since the card is already active, the script probably won't be able to unload the old driver, so you will probably need to reboot after running the script.

If you find out the new driver does not work at all, the way to return the system configuration back to the starting point will be:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf
sudo dkms remove rtlwifi-new/0.6 --all
```